# Dynamic queries in JPA (Query by Example)

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have these structures:

```
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Customer.class)
    private Customer customer;

    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
    private Address address;
    private String invoiceType;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Customer customer;
    // getters and setters
}
```

And the InvoiceRepository is something like this:

```
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, String> {
    List<Invoice> findByCustomerIdAndAddressId(long customerId, long addressId);
    List<Invoice> findByCustomerId(long customerId);
    List<Invoice> findByCustomerIdAndInvoiceType(long customerId, String invoiceType);
}
```

And the repository it's being autowired on InvoiceService.

I've read about Query by Example, but I'm not sure if I can use it with JPA. Can I use without Hibernate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood JPA and Hibernate.

Just to clarify, JPA is a specification. JPA stands for Java Persistence API. It has various implementations - so called providers - , for example OpenJPA, EclipseLink, Hibernate, etc.

Imagine this like having plenty of interfaces - basically the API - and you don't have implementation for them. This is JPA.

The implementations for the interfaces is done by a provider, for example Hibernate.

Of course you can use JPA without the Hibernate provider, however you have to use another one (EclipseLink, OpenJPA, etc.).